# Need help for this proof in Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm beginning to study Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory* and I'm trying to understand this theorem when $M$ is finitely generated:

[image]
[image]

I have the following questions:

First question:

> It seems Matsumura is cheating because $M$ doesn't necessarily has a basis (it's not free), in fact it's exactly we want to prove, he assumes true in the first line.

Second question:

> Why there exists such map $\psi$? What I know is this exact sequence splits:
>
> $$0\to \ker\varphi\to F\to M\to 0$$
>
> Where the first non trivial homomorphism is the canonical injection
>   and the second one $\varphi$, since this sequence splits we have:
>   $F=\ker\varphi\oplus M$ or equivalently there is a homomorphism
>   $j:M\to F$ such that $\varphi j=1_M$. How can I deduce what the author
>   says?

Third question:

> Why the red line implies the blue one?

If anyone could help me with at least one of these questions it would help me a lot.

Sorry for anything, I'm a really beginner in this subject.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question:

Note that a minimal basis in the sense of Matsumura is not a basis in the sense of it being free, it is just a set of generators such that any proper subset does not generate your module. Now, any finite $A$-module has a minimal basis all of the same cardinality (for properties of minimal bases, see pg. 8 of the Commutative Ring theory). So he is not assuming it to be free.

Answer to second question:

Note that in your case, $ker \varphi = K $. Thus it follows from the direct sum deomposition you mentioned.

Answer to third question:
Going to the residue field, you know that $K$ is zero (by the definition of the minimal basis property) and this implies that $K=mK$.

Comment: In the second question: yes, I know it follows the direct sum decomposition I mentioned, but why?

Comment: Do you mean why the direct sum decomposition follows from the existence of a map? In that case, maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma can help you. It is also a good exercise to prove it by yourself.

Comment: Could you explain more detai about the last two paragraphs?